# Why do I have to cast the return of Constructor.newInstance?

Tags: java

According to the docs, newInstance() returns a T: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()

So if I have a method that returns T, why do I have to cast the return of Constructor.newInstance() to T?

```
protected <T extends ParentClass> T getConfig() {
  return (T) _childClassConstructor.newInstance();
```

Comment: What is the type of `_childClassConstructor`?

Comment:  That is a hint to the answer 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are figments of the compiler's imagination: The runtime (`java.exe`) doesn't know what it means, doesn't care, and mostly, doesn't even have this information ('erasure'). Yes, public signatures do carry generics info, but it's literally a comment as far as the runtime is concerned.

Thus, what use is it, really?

Well, it links things. It makes it possible to tell the compiler: So, I have this method, and it takes 2 parameters. These 2 parameters can be whatever you please, but, they must be the same type. If they aren't, the runtime isn't going to core dump or anything, just.. that'd mean the software is buggy. So, if you see code that fails this rule, please mark it with an error so I know I need to fix it.

That's all generics does. But that's rather useful, fortunately!

If you use generics and they show up in only one place, that's basically useless, or hacky. You've done that here: T shows up only once, as the return type of this method, and nowhere else. That's, virtually always, an indication that the author of the code does not understand what java's generics do.

In this case, what you've effectively done is turn this into a voodoo magic any-method - this method will adapt its return type to be whatever the caller wishes it to be. Given `class Parent` and `class Joe extends Parent` and `class Jane extends Parent`, then this will work:

```
Joe c = getConfig();
```

How can `getConfig()` know that its return type is in fact `Joe`? It doesn't. It adapts to be what you want it to be.

Which is a bad thing - because if you look at the code, that's not *actually* how it works here:

```
class ConfigTool {
    private final Class<? extends Parent> c;

    public ConfigTool(Class<? extends Parent> c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public <T extends ParentClass> T getConfig() {
        return (T) c.newInstance();
    }
}
```

and:

```
ConfigTool tool = new ConfigTool(Jane.class);
Joe joe = tool.getConfig();
```

will just compile. And, of course, explode at runtime: the `getConfig()` method ends up making an instance of `Jane`, which cannot be assigned to a variable of type Joe, which suggests that there is no easy 'this is how to fix your code' answer, because what you've written is meaningless / impossible.

What you presumably intend is for one of two things:

Either:

```
public ParentClass getConfig() {
    return c.newInstance();
}
```

Sure, maybe `c` is the Class instance representing Joe, but it could also be Jane. The only promise your API can make is that, whatever that Class instance may be, whatever instance it makes will be assignable to a variable of type Parent. After all, `Parent p = new Joe();` is valid, as is `Parent p = new Jane();`.

There's no need to involve generics. Generics is one 'meta' level higher: It's turning the type system itself into a programming language, and you don't need to do that, here.

The other alternative that you may want is to link the return type of your `getConfig()` method to the particular type of the Class instance for this object:

```
class ConfigTool<T extends Parent> {
    private final Class<T> c;

    public ConfigTool(Class<T> c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public T getConfig() {
        return c.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Note how in this code there is absolutely no need for that cast, the above compiles as written. The generics are also useful, as T shows up in 2 places: Both the `Class<T>` parameter in the constructor, as well as the `T` return type of the `getConfig` method (its appearance in `class Parent<T>` doesn't count, that isn't using it, that's defining its existence).

Comment: Thank you for such a great explanation!